# How to import webservices in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to import the webservices that are in the WSDL into Jmeter using SOAP/XML-RPC request. But I didn't see anything with the 'Import' or LoadWSDL option. I saw this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IsmrHK6FPjA which has the webservice(SOAP) request which I cant see it in my Jmeter version.
The reason I'm asking is because in each SOAP/XML-RPC Data, I've to open SOAPUI to get blank request and then paste it in the Jmter. We have hundreds of webservices to test and this method is getting very lengthy process.
Is there a way in Jmeter to create blank requests like SOAP UI  if I give the wsdl URL and it generates all possible requests for us. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can someone please answer my query?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such import feature in JMeter.

But a way to do it is to put JMeter as a proxy for SOAP UI using [HTTP Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder),  then you would avoid Copy/paste thing.

Read also this for up to date way of testing webservices:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html

Comment: I've read that documentation already. Thanks for pointing that. Proxy wont here in our applications because the webservices has no connection with the web applications. There are created as  one offs connecting to dms directly. Is there any other way to import?

Comment: Can someone answer my question please?

Answer (score 0):

As per the jmeter latest version help WebService(SOAP) Request sampler is DEPRECATED. This sampler is having load WSDL option. Try older version of jmeter..